# Proguard warning for Java classes using OpenJDK

Tags: java, proguard

When I use openJDK instead of Java JRE,

```
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\lib'
```

It gives warnings that the Java class cannot be found.
Is there a way to solve this?

Sample:

> [proguard] Warning:
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.IRunnableWithProgress: can't find
>   superclass or interface java.lang.Object  [proguard] Warning:
>   org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore: can't find superclass
>   or interface java.lang.Object  [proguard] Warning:
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry: can't find superclass or
>   interface java.lang.Object  [proguard] Warning:
>   org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources: can't find superclass or
>   interface java.lang.Object  [proguard] Warning:
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument: can't find superclass or interface
>   java.lang.Object
>
> [proguard] Warning:
>   **javaclass**: can't find
>   referenced class java.lang.String  [proguard] Warning:
>   **javaclass**: can't find
>   referenced class java.lang.String

Note:
-ignorewarnings does not help since it will produce an error regarding interfaces

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out that Proguard does not support openJDK 11 yet.
I used openJDK 10.0.2 and in the library jars I specified the path to the folder of jmods instead of libs

> -libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\jmods'

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the -libraryjars option specifies a classpath, i.e. location where .class files can be found.  Either that's a directory holding those .class files or else it is a jar (or a list thereof) containing the .class files.  For referencing the runtime, specify the list of .jar files that constitute it (and that you effectively use).

Comment: Hello, that location contains the jrt-fs.jar of the JDK which contains the class files. But it seems it can't find the Java.lang.String or other classes.

Comment: If you provide a directory name, the system won't inspect any jars that are there.  You have to name them explicitly, or perhaps implicitly with *.jar as in -libraryjars <path>/*.jar.

Comment: Hello, I've added an answer below. Thanks for your help!